# Types of graphs for this

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, random-graphs, experimental-mathematics

How many ways could this be graphed, in a way such that it shows that the degree or slope of a surface affects the average speed. I think T1, t2 etc means at second 1, second 2. This was done using a ticker timer. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw different graphs.  One would just plot degrees slope vs average speed to show the relation.  Presumably $T_1$ means the time to get to position $1$-before drawing a graph it is good to know what the data means.  You could draw a graph with positions $1,2,3,4$ across the bottom (are they evenly spaced) and time to reach each position up the left.  Draw three curves, one for each slope.